# Checking the passed variable

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to check if the passed variable in a function is a specific text? For example, I have a function:

```
Function dateCheck2(dateValue As String) As Boolean

If IIf(IsDate(frmResponse.txtEndDate), Format(CDate(frmResponse.txtEndDate), _
    "mm\/dd\/yyyy"), "") = dateValue Then
    dateCheck2 = True
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Then I have to call this in a UForm, lets say :

```
dateCheck2(sample)
```

What I want is to check if the passed variable is `sample`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You think to check variable name, or variable content? If content, then just use if and compare it to whatever you wana...

Comment: @LubošSuk The Variable name :)

Comment: Then i dont thik its possbile. What you can do is to add another param to your function, which will hold variable name. But when you pass variable to function i think its lost everything info about itself. Its just pass values to new variable and old name and etc is not known in function

Comment: ok. Thanks for this :)

Comment: Why do you need to check the variable name instead of its content?

Comment: Yeah, what is that you are really trying to do? Why don't you do your validation before you call the `dateCheck2`? It sounds like you are not the one passing the variable to the function...

Comment: @Vegard So that I can make only one function that can hold two different varaiable names. Thanks.

Comment: What? That makes no sense. A `Function` doesn't "hold" anything, it performs some action and returns a value. Can you explain more closely what you want to do?

Comment: @kruk22 and why you need one function with two different variable names? Its nonsence! If variables are different date type, or you need diferent operations, make another function.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create your own class (in VBA its called data type) which will hold variable name and values. Something like this

```
Public Type myFluffyType
     fluffyName as string
     fluffyValue as string
end Type
```

Then you can dim your variable like this

```
Dim fluffyVariable as myFluffyType
```

and initialize

```
fluffyVariable.fluffyName = "fluffyVariable"
fluffyVariable.fluffyValue = "notSoMuchFluffyValue"
```

and then when you passed it into your function you have all informations you need

Edit: on your problem you can do something like this. But im not sure what you exactly wana do next

```
Public type myType
     varName as string
     varValue as string
end type


Sub callDateCheck2
   Dim sample as myType
   sample.varName = "sample"
   sample.varValue = "whateverValues" 
   Call dateCheck2(sample)
end sub


Function dateCheck2(dateValue As myType) As Boolean

if dateValue.varName = "sample" then
    msgbox "everything ok"
else
    msgbox "bad variable name"
    end function
end if

If IIf(IsDate(frmResponse.txtEndDate), Format(CDate(frmResponse.txtEndDate), _
    "mm\/dd\/yyyy"), "") = dateValue Then
    dateCheck2 = True
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Comment: can you give me an exmaple on how to use this based on my problem ? Thanks

Comment: @kruk22 updated probably to what you wana, but im not sure with that

Comment: Weew .. These destroys the rest of my scripts . . heheh

Comment: @kruk22 i dont know rest of your scripts, so this is not a instant solution... it can only gave you another point of view

Comment: Yes. I understand :) Thanks for It!